# Rethinkdb convert an array of objects to a single object

Tags: javascript, functional-programming, rethinkdb, nosql

How would one convert the following:

```
[{
  "name": "annoying data",
  "status": "evil",
  "frustration": [
   {
      "name": "foo",
      "value": 1
    },
    {
      "name": "bar",
      "value": 2
    },
    {
      "name": "baz",
      "value": 3
    }
  ]
}...]
```

To this output:

```
[{
  "name": "annoying data",
  "status": "evil",
  "foo": 1,
  "bar": 2,
  "baz": 3
}...]
```

from within a rethink query?

We have a stored third-party API response that I am attempting to transform into something useful.  In my mind there are 2 things I need to accomplish to reach my end goal of sane data output.

1. transform the `frustration` array into an object using `name` as the keys and `value` as the values.
2. merge the newly transformed `frustration` object into the parent object.

I have a possible solution for step 2:

```
.map(function(row) {
    row.pluck('name', 'status').merge(row('frustration'))
})
```

But I'm getting nowhere with step one.  Any ideas are much appreciated!

Current full query (names changed to protect... me!):

```
r.db('test').table('evil_things').map(function(row) {
  var x = row('a')('tree')('children')
        .nth(0)('children')
        .nth(0)
        .map(function(x) {
          return x('children');
        })
        .concatMap(function(x) {
          return x.pluck('name', 'value');
        })
  ;

  return {
    'name': row('name'),
    'status': row('status'),
    'frustration': x
  };
}).filter(function(row) {
  return r.expr(['FOO','BAR','BAZ']).contains(row('name').upcase());
})
.orderBy('status');
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are in correct way.

You can create an objects from a key-value list of data with `object`. But `object` receive a list of parameters, instead of an array so you need `args`.

`frustation` is an array with each document as object, you need a way to turn it into a list of flatten array, meaning from this array

`[{key1: val1}, {key2: val2},...]`

we turn it to

`[key1, val1, key2, val2,...]`

to feed into `args` for `object`. That's the job of `concatMap`.

Let's try this:

```
r.expr([{
  "name": "annoying data",
  "status": "evil",
  "frustration": [
    {
      "name": "foo",
      "value": 1
    },
    {
      "name": "bar",
      "value": 2
    },
    {
      "name": "baz",
      "value": 3
    }
  ]
}])
.map(function(doc) {
  return doc.pluck("name", "status").merge(
    r.object(r.args(doc('frustration')
     .concatMap(function(frustration) { return [frustration("name"), frustration("value")] })
    ))
  )
})
```

Result:

```
[
{
"bar": 2 ,
"baz": 3 ,
"foo": 1 ,
"name":  "annoying data" ,
"status":  "evil"
}
]
```

Hope it helps:

Comment: awesome thank you for the push in the correct direction.

Comment: Hey Scull7, You can read more about this on this book(my book btw): https://github.com/kureikain/simplyrethink/

Answer (score 2):

Something like this should work:

```
.map(function(row) {
  return row.pluck('name', 'status').merge(
    row('frustration').map(function(x){ return [x['name'], x['value']]; }).coerceTo('object'))
})
```

Comment: That's awesome! Saved me so much time :) For javascript it has to be `return [x('name'), x('value')]`